# Jquery target individual elements with same class for lightbox

Tags: jquery, class, lightbox, target

I'm having trouble with my lightbox which is set up and working at http://upsidecreative.com.au/index-new.html

The problem is, each lightbox full image has a class of .boximage and when I click on the thumbnail (class .lightbox) the javascript runs ...

```
    $('.lightbox').click(function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

(the .backdrop is the greying out of the background behind the lightbox and the .box is the box which has the image and caption inside it as well as the close button)

It works in that it changes display of the lightbox full image from 'none' to ' block' but it displays all images at once since they all have the class of .boximage.

Is there a way to target each individual lightbox full image here to display the correct one?

Many thanks,
Greg

Comment: I've now got this working, thanks to DinoMyte, however, the fix has killed the other functionality of closing the lightbox full image by clicking on the backdrop (.backdrop) or the close button (.close) 

 $('.close').click(function(){
   $('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
  });
  
  $('.backdrop').click(function(){
   
   $('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
  
  });

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
$('.lightbox').click(function()
{
     $(this).find('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'block');
 });
```

This would target the '.lightbox' element which invoked the function.

EDIT :

Based on the structure of your DOM , this is what you can do for all click events.

```
    $('.lightbox').click(function () {
    /* Assigns the unique generated id of the element in the DOM to a variable called id. */
            var id = $(this)[0].uniqueNumber;
   // Iterate through each item and find the corresponding element in the DOM with the same unique id.
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.lightbox').each(function () {
                if ($(this)[0].uniqueNumber == id) {
   // If match is found, search for elements with the following css and show them.
                    $(this).find('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'block');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

To hide elements with 'box' and 'boximage' classes,

```
     $('.close').click(function () {

            var id = $(this).parent()[0].uniqueNumber; 

            $(this).parent().parent().find('.box').each(function () {
                if ($(this)[0].uniqueNumber == id) { 
                    $(this).find('.box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');   return false;
                }
            });      
        });
```

Comment: Scratch that, I put it all in the <a> link and it works. Thanks DinoMyte, great work! (originally I had the thumbail in a <a></a> and then the full image in a <div></div>

Comment: Just wondering ...

That works for displaying the correct full lightbox image, but it has killed the other functionality (which was closing the lightbox when the backdrop or the close 'x' was clicked).

Any ideas?

Here is the other javascript ...

$('.close').click(function(){
   $('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
  });
  
  $('.backdrop').click(function(){
   
   $('.backdrop, .box, .boximage').css('display', 'none');
  
  });

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.

Comment: @GregJorss : I've added code for handling click events. just follow the instructions after 'EDIT'.